# Getting All POST Variables instead of hidden fields and submit button

Tags: php, html

I have a form where text fields are created dynamically with the names unknown. I am trying to get those text fields names and values and using the following PHP code.

```
foreach ($_POST as $key => $entry)
{
     if (is_array($entry))
     {
        foreach($entry as $value)
        {
           print $key . ": " . $value . "<br>";
        }
     }
    else 
     {
        print $key . ": " . $entry . "<br>";
     }
}
```

But the problem is that it gets all the hidden fields and submit button values as well. How can I prevent that from happening?

Comment: Do you want them to be inserted in Database? If yes, you do not needs to remove them

Comment: poor english. i didn't understand anything

Comment: Do you want to display the posted values?

Comment: @Shakti, yes I want to save them in the DB, but it is the UPDATE query and the field name is the ID of the record against I which I will update it.It is like this multiple input fields <input type="text"  value="Kitchen" id="51076" name="51076">

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
foreach ($_POST as $key => $entry)
{
     if ($key == "button_submit") continue;
     if ($key == "hidden_field") continue;
     if ($key == "hidden_field2") continue;
     if ($key == "hidden_field3") continue;
     if (is_array($entry))
     {
        foreach($entry as $value)
        {
           print $key . ": " . $value . "<br>";
        }
     }
    else 
     {
        print $key . ": " . $entry . "<br>";
     }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! I know the names of hidden field and have added the conditions. It is working perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

unless and until you know names of the fields , you can not put constrains.

in your case one alternative solution is you can put condition in loop

like

```
if($key == 'btn_name')
{

   code....

}

else{

   code...

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Essentially, a hidden field and a submit button are form elements that should (must!) be send as part of a POST request, if they are inside `<form>` tags. This is standard behavior. Otherwise a server would not be able to determine the value of a hidden field, or determine which submit button was pressed.

So, you'll have to make exceptions if you don't want to process these fields. A simple workaround is to use a naming-convention (i.e., `hidden_` or `submit_`) for the fields you do not wish to process, then you simply check whether a key starts with one of those unwanted names.